# Javascript regex to exclude all subdirectories of a given directory in a URL

Tags: javascript, regex, url

Suppose you have a domain `http://www.somedomainname.com`

There is code that should run **on all pages except anything deeper in the some-directory: `http://www.somedomainname.com/some-directory/anything`**

I tried:

```
(function($) {

    $(document).ready(function() {

        var isBad = !!window.location.pathname.match(/^\/some-directory/*);
        if ( !isBad ) {

            // RUN CODE
        }

    });

}(jQuery));
```

And Chrome console told me my regex was bad. I gambled using `*` as a wildcard, but it isn't working as I had hoped.

Comment: Must it be RegEx? Why not `window.location.pathname.indexOf('/some-directory/')`?

Comment: Using the stackoverflow url above, I think this syntax will work for you: `window.location.pathname.match(/^\/questions\//)` (but you'd use some-directory instead of questions ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If some-directory is always the first thing in the pathname you don't really need wildcards, but you should handle the possible missing trailing slash (where a file like index.html is often served):

```js
var testing = "";
console.log(testing = "/some-directory", testing.match(/^\/some-directory[\/]?/));
console.log(testing = "/some-directory/", testing.match(/^\/some-directory[\/]?/));
console.log(testing = "/some-directory/something", testing.match(/^\/some-directory[\/]?/));
console.log(testing = "/wont-find/some-directory", testing.match(/^\/some-directory[\/]?/));
```

If you need to find that directory name anywhere in your path you can add a wildcard at the beginning:

```js
var testing = "";
console.log(testing = "/some-other-dir/some-directory", testing.match(/^.*\/some-directory[\/]?/));
console.log(testing = "/some-other-dir/some-directory/", testing.match(/^.*\/some-directory[\/]?/));
console.log(testing = "/some-other-dir/some-directory/something", testing.match(/^.*\/some-directory[\/]?/));
```

Both examples require the leading slash however.

Answer (score 0):

What about this simple Debuggex regex ?

```
^\/some-directory\/[\s\S]
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/CkP9jcF-QIhVYWF-)